# Fetch row and Save in Variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, fetch, sqldatareader

I am writing a WPF C# application and I want to save fetched row in a variable.

```
SqlDataAdapter connAdp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  * FROM users WHERE (username = '"+uname+"') AND (password = '"+pass+"');",conn);
SqlDataReader fetchInfo = null;
fetchInfo = conn.ExecuteReader();
fetchInfo.Read();
```

But when I try to build my application it gives error

> ExecuteReader not defined

I tried this code also:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
DataRow row = dt.Rows["username"];
```

But it gives error too. I am new to C# and WPF, so can anyone tell how I fetch data from SQL Server and store in a variable or array?

Answer (score 0):

I sort it out myself

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM users WHERE (username = '" + uname + "') AND (password = '" + pass + "');", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Here it is guys, i hope it help noobs. You can fetch it with `dr.Read()`

Comment: You should use the [using statement](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyTheUsingStatementIsBetterThanASharpStickInTheEyeAndASqlConnectionRefactoringExample.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It is always SqlCommand.ExecuteReader not Sqlconnection.ExecuteReader.

```
    SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM users WHERE (username = '"+uname+"') AND (password = '"+pass+"');",conn);
conn.open();
            SqlDatareader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
While(dr.Read())
{
//Fecth your values from reader and store it in your variable
}
conn.close();
```

Comment: how to get value by column name